# "discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions" when trying to send a message with embed

Tags: python, discord.py

**Discord.py version: 2.3.0**

I've tried to send a message with embed. Without embed it works just fine, but with it "403 forbidden" error shows up in my log.

So far I've implemented embeds in app_commands and they worked normally, but in chat commands the "403 forbidden" occurs. "intents.message_content" is set to True.

Embed is defined in class "CountryEmbed" like this:

```py
class CountryEmbed(discord.Embed):
    def __init__(self, name: str, capital: str, population: int, area: float):
        super().__init__(
            title="Country info",
            colour=discord.Colour.from_str("#a23331"),
            type='rich',
        )

        self.add_field(name='Name', value=name, inline=True)
        self.add_field(name='Capital', value=capital, inline=True)
        self.add_field(name='Population', value=str(population), inline=True)
        self.add_field(name='Area', value=f"{area} m²", inline=True)
```

The command is implemented like this (inside cog):

```
   @commands.command(name='countries')
    async def countries(self, ctx: commands.Context, arg: str) -> None:
       ...
```

**Full traceback:**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Projects\Python\Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Documents\Projects\Python\Bot\cogs\webscrap.py", line 31, in countries
    await ctx.send(embed=CountryEmbed(name=data['name'], capital=data['capital'], population=data['population'], area=data['area']))
  File "D:\Documents\Projects\Python\Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\context.py", line 1024, in send
    return await super().send(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Documents\Projects\Python\Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1562, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Documents\Projects\Python\Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 739, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Projects\Python\Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\Documents\Projects\Python\Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Documents\Projects\Python\Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I've tried:

- Change "embed" to "embeds" in ctx.send:

From:

```py
await ctx.send(embed=CountryEmbed(name=data['name'], capital=data['capital'], population=data['population'], area=data['area'])
```

To:

```py
await ctx.send(embeds=[CountryEmbed(name=data['name'], capital=data['capital'], population=data['population'], area=data['area'])])
```

- Send more simple embed like this:

```py
await ctx.send(content="a", embed=discord.Embed(title='Test', description="ddsdf"))
```

It worked, but it only sends message with content "a" **without** embed. It doesn't output any error in the log, though.

- Tried to remove "inline" fields
- Tried to read the docs and search in Google. Nothing helped. Documentation examples didn't help, either.

Please, point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. You need to check bot role permissions on your server. For embeds it should have:

- send messages
- embed links
- attach files

Also you can have some role overrides. You may want to use something like https://github.com/Gorialis/jishaku to pinpoint role overrides. So that's all. Cheers!